# classifier4j class not found exception on addMatch() method

Tags: java, exception, classification

i have a strange behaviour when trying to use bayesian classifier class from classifier4j package

basically my code is:

```
String test_string = "some bla bla web designers in here whatever";
SimpleWordsDataSource wds = new SimpleWordsDataSource();
BayesianClassifier classifier = new BayesianClassifier(wds);
wds.addMatch("Web Design")
Double d = classifier.classify(test_string);
```

what i'm getting when trying to run this code is:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at net.sf.classifier4J.bayesian.WordProbability.calculateProbability(WordProbability.java:167)
    at net.sf.classifier4J.bayesian.WordProbability.setMatchingCount(WordProbability.java:138)
    at net.sf.classifier4J.bayesian.WordProbability.<init>(WordProbability.java:115)
    at net.sf.classifier4J.bayesian.SimpleWordsDataSource.addMatch(SimpleWordsDataSource.java:94)
    at tothego_classifier_test.Main.main(Main.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 5 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

which is pretty annoying since i've been trying to run a simple hello-world test (as in the website's usage part). I'm on netbeans 6.9 and i've ofc included classifier4j 0.6 jar and optional jar, also have the correct import statements in my main class.
I know Nick Lothian contributes here, so i tought would be good asking!
thanks everybody for efforts

Comment: i did not mention: when i run the code without the wds.addmatch() statement, it runs from beginning to end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i solved the problem, and here we go with a quick howto for everyone:

- http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi click on this link and download the binary file
- unzip the file you just downloaded
- add commons-logging-xxx.jar, commons-logging-adapters.jar, commons-logging-api.jar to your CLASSPATH / project libs (i tried an awful lot, and it only seems to work with the whole jars included)
- rebuild and rerun

hope this is helpful :)